# populate with getJSON in html

Tags: jquery, json

I'm learning frontend, and make some exercice for my own project. 
I would like to populate a "p" with this API but I don't see how:

```
$.getJSON('http://www.hqcasanova.com/co2?callback=?', function (data) {
            //Fiddle with JSON data
        });
```

I's an CO2 level real time api.
Thanks you for your help

Comment: loop each value of the API then use append to add each value on the `p`

Comment: You have all what you need in the documentation of jquery take a look: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/